# Create bindable event handler in custom view cell

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have created a native ViewCellRenderer for view cell that is being used in list view For UWP by following Microsoft article [Customizing View Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell).
The article explains how to create bindable properties for a view cell that can be displayed using the native controls. What I want is to be able to create a bindable event handler so that I can bind this event with native UWP code say Tapped event of Textblock.

Example- On the tapped event of Textblock 'Name' i want to navigate to some another page. The navigation logic is written inside the view model for the page where I am using the list view with custom view cell. How can I create a bindable event handler in custom view cell so that I could bind it with the Tapped event of native code.

Comment: Please show and include what you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [similar case](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137911/how-to-create-bindable-event-handler-in-custom-view-cell) in Xamarin. And our team member has replied, For your requirement, the key point is using [`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to bind TextBlock's `Tapped` event with the command that defined in the custom view cell.

**Xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
            <Grid>                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextName}" >
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding TappedCommand}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>        
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you could invoke navigate action in `TappedCommand` method.

Comment: Thanks a  lot that is what I was looking for.
Just one more concern how do it pass the complete model as parameter to command in the above sample, since CommandParameter= "{Binding .}" doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: For command parameter you could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51436851/7254781) reply.