# how to properly use item click in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-10-universal

I have a gridview, which presents all of the users I have in my database, and their details, I want to be able, on the click of a user(on the gridview), that it's details will appear separately on the side of the grid view, and there I could change them accordingly. However, I'm not sure how to do so. I have the   ItemClick event in my gridview, and It does recognize if I click on an item, but I don't know how to get that specific clicked user's details, for me to present them on the side. I also have another problem- for some reason It doesn't recognize nor let me click on any of the top row items on the grid view-only the ones below it, does anyone know why?

this is my XAML :

```
<Page
x:Class="My_Little_Animal.ShowUsers"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:My_Little_Animal"
xmlns:data="using:My_Little_Animal" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/changeUserDetailesBackground.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="147*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView Name="grid1" ItemClick="grid1_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="-70,151,692,50" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:User">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel Margin="100,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Name="t1" FontSize="20" GotFocus="t1_GotFocus" Text="{x:Bind UserId}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="t2" FontSize="20" GotFocus="t2_GotFocus" Text="{x:Bind Password}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="t3" FontSize="20" GotFocus="t3_GotFocus" Text="{x:Bind UserName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="t4" FontSize="20" GotFocus="t4_GotFocus" Text="{x:Bind Email}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <Canvas>
        <Image Name="loginTitle" Source="/Assets/ShowUsersTitle.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.Left="-325" Canvas.Top="-120" Height="462" Width="1875"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Name="ResultTextBlock" FontSize="24" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Height="169" Margin="0,0,0,-69"/>
        <Image Name="editTheUserName" Width="100" Height="35" Visibility="Visible"  Source="/Assets/editIcon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="852" Canvas.Top="226" />
        <Image Name="CancelTheUserNamE" Width="100" Height="35" Visibility="Visible" Source="/Assets/xIcon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.485,0.529" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="848" Canvas.Top="224" />
        <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Name="theUserItself" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"  FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="25"  Text="your user name  " RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,1.165" Foreground="#FF283D6C" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1103" Canvas.Top="219" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBlock Name="userName" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"  FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="25"  Text="User Name : " RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,1.165" TextDecorations="Underline" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="922" Canvas.Top="224"/>
        <TextBox Visibility="Visible" Width="200" Name="UserNameText" MaxLength="50" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF23677D" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1099" Canvas.Top="223" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button Visibility="Visible" Name="changeuserName" Height="49" Width="140" FontSize="20" Content="change" FontWeight="ExtraBold" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FF191A5C" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,0.536" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1305" Canvas.Top="210" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Image Name="editTheEmail" Canvas.Top="286" Canvas.Left="850" Width="100" Height="35" Visibility="Visible"  Source="/Assets/editIcon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.49,0.557" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Image Name="CancelTheEmail" Width="100" Height="35" Visibility="Visible" Source="/Assets/xIcon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.485,0.529" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="847" Canvas.Top="284" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Name="theEmailItself" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"  FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="25"  Text="your email " RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,1.165" Foreground="#FF283D6C" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1105" Canvas.Top="276"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Email" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"  FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="25"  Text="Email : " RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,1.165" TextDecorations="Underline" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="921" Canvas.Top="283" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBox Visibility="Visible" Width="200" Name="EmailText" MaxLength="50" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF23677D" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1093" Canvas.Top="284" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button Visibility="Visible" Name="changeEmail" Height="49" Width="140" FontSize="20" Content="change" FontWeight="ExtraBold" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FF191A5C" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,0.536" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Left="1302" Canvas.Top="274" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Image Name="theReturn" Height="100" Width="100" Tapped="theReturn_Tapped_1" Source="/Assets/theReturnIcon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.493,0.496" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.Left="65" Canvas.Top="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The c# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using Windows.UI.Popups;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace My_Little_Animal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ShowUsers : Page
    {
        regitration.regitrationSoapClient cal;
        public ShowUsers()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            cal = new regitration.regitrationSoapClient();
            getData();
        }

        public async void getData()
        {
            regitration.getUserTableResponseGetUserTableResult r = await cal.getUserTableAsync();
            List<User> theUserList = new List<User>();
            User u = null;
            XmlReader xr = r.Any1.CreateReader();
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(xr);
            XmlNodeList theXmlList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Table");
            foreach (XmlElement item in theXmlList)
            {
                u = new User();
                foreach (XmlNode node in item.ChildNodes)
                {
                    switch (node.Name)
                    {
                        case "userId": u.UserId = int.Parse(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "password": u.Password = node.InnerText; break;
                        case "userName": u.UserName = node.InnerText; break;
                        case "email": u.Email = node.InnerText; break;
                    }
                }
                theUserList.Add(u);
            }
            grid1.ItemsSource = theUserList;
        }

        private async void grid1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("The item that was clicked is : ");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        private void t1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void t2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void t3_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void t4_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void theReturn_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Administrator));
        }
    }
}
```

I will be so thankful for any help, it's really important for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't know how to get that specific clicked user's details, for me to present them on the side.

There are many ways to get the item in item click event. if you have used **MVVM** pattern, the recommend way is binding command. For more you could refer [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428298/how-to-handle-itemclick-for-nested-listview-in-mvvm-pattern/51436851#51436851).

In general, you could subscribe `ItemClick` event and get `ClickedItem` from event [`ItemClickEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs)

**Example**

```
private void VideoGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var vedio = e.ClickedItem as VideoItem;          
    var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(vedio.videoUri))); 
    mediaPlayerElement.Source = item;
}
```

> I also have another problem- for some reason It doesn't recognize nor let me click on any of the top row items on the grid view-only the ones below it, does anyone know why?

I could not reproduce this issue, please check if there is some element cover the top row up cause the grid view could not be clicked.