# Display A Gridview Inside A Gridview

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp, textblock

I have a gridview with the name "majorGridView" inside a gridview with the name "assessmenGridView" whose data is data binding

XAML:

```
<GridView x:Name="asesmenGridView">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UserControl>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel
                        x:Name="judulStack"
                        Height="40">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="judulT"
                                                        Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>   
                    <GridView
                        x:Name="majorGridView">
                                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                                            <UserControl>
                                                                <Grid>
                                                                    <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="kelasT"
                                                                        Text="{Binding Major}"/>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </UserControl>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How to display binding text on "majorGridView" ? Because if I use the code below, I will get an error message: "The name 'majorGridView' does not exist in the current context"

Code:

```
    ObservableCollection<Ujian> ujiandatasource = new ObservableCollection<Ujian>();
            ObservableCollection<Ujian> majordatasource = new ObservableCollection<Ujian>();
     string urlPath = "https://pto.study.id/api/" + ((App)(App.Current)).AsesmenCode + "-do/s2/choose-exam/" + guru.ID;
                            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",
                                string.Format("Bearer {0}", tkn));
                            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            try
                            {
                                JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);
                                foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
                                {
                                    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
    JsonArray majorArray = groupObject["majors"].GetArray();
                                    foreach(JsonValue majorValue in majorArray)
                                    {
                                        JsonObject majorObject = majorValue.GetObject();
                                        string major = majorObject["major"].GetString();
    
                                        Ujian ujian1 = new Ujian();
                                        ujian1.Major = major + ", ";
    
                                        majordatasource.Add(ujian1);
                                        majorGridView.ItemsSource = majordatasource;
                                    }
    Ujian ujian = new Ujian();
                                    ujian.Title = title;
     ujiandatasource.Add(ujian);
    asesmenGridView.ItemsSource = ujiandatasource;
}
```

Ujian.cs

```
class Ujian
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to read your code, it's a little bit mess.  What is the Ujian class? And what's the itemsource for `asesmenGridView`. It looks like you haven't set an itemssource for the `asesmenGridView`. There are several items in `asesmenGridView` and they all called `majorGridView`. I suspect that is the reason.

Comment: I've edited the code above for the "assessmenGridView.ItemsSource" and added "Ujian.cs"
For set "asesmenGridView" it worked, but for set "majorGridView" inside "assessmenGridView" it didn't work with an error message: "The name 'majorGridView' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

> The name 'majorGridView' does not exist in the current context"

`majorGridView` in the parent `DataTemplate`, so we can't access `majorGridView` with name directly. For this scenario, we often use nested collection apply the value generally. And here is [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51436851/7254781) that you could refer to.

Comment: What if the data in the gridview is data binding?

Comment: Could you explain   *data in the gridview gridview is data binding*  ?

Comment: Any updates for this thread?